# How to parse many json files using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to parse in my HTML page many JSON files:
Here is my service's code:

```
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) {
var tab = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'] 
for(i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
  return $http.get(tab[i]) 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); }
}]);
```

In my HTML file , I only have the information of the first json file.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<tr>
<td>{{data.nm}}</td>
<td>{{data.cty}}</td>   
<td>{{data.hse}}</td>
<td>{{data.yrs}}</td> 
</tr>
```

Is there something to add in my HTML so I can get the information from all the json files or any other solution?

Comment: Is it normal that you `return` many times within the `for` loop? It seems to me that you're only going to fetch the first url data with this snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you return in the first iteration in your for loop, so you only get the data for the first url. Don't return right away, assign a scope variable to your data:

**Factory**

```
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) {        
    function getLists() {
        var tab = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
        var list = [];
        for(i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
        $http.get(tab[i]) 
            .then(function(res) {
                list.push(res.data);
            });
        }
        return list;
    }

    return {
        getLists: getLists
    };
]);
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.list = myapp.getLists();
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list">
  <td>{{d.nm}}</td>
  <td>{{d.cty}}</td>   
  <td>{{d.hse}}</td>
  <td>{{d.yrs}}</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't think so `i` value will be persisted correctly while inserting value in `data` object inside`.then` function, you should pass `i` value to `.then` callback function by having anonymous function..

Comment: If the order of insertion doesn't matter to OP, then yes its correct. Thanks +1 :)

Comment: I got this error Provider 'myapp' must return a vlaue from $get factory method. In my controller I had:
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'myapp', function($scope, myapp) {
  myapp.success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
  });
}]);
how should I modify it?

Comment: Wow, I just realized it's a factory, not a controller. One sec!

Comment: @nour Updated, could you check please?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is $q.all

I would solve the problem like this

```
angular.module('app').factory('myRequestsFactory',function($http, apiHost) {

    var myRequestsFactory = {};

    myRequestsFactory.geturl1 = function() {
        return $http.get(url1);
    };

    myRequestsFactory.geturl2 = function() {
        return $http.get(url2);
    };

    myRequestsFactory.geturl3 = function() {
        return $http.get(url3);
    };

    return myRequestsFactory;
});
```

Then I would create an other service

```
angular.module('app').factory('helperService',function($q, myRequestsFactory) {

    var helperService = {};

    helperService.GetAll = function() {
      return $q.all([
                      myRequestsFactory.geturl1(), 
                      myRequestsFactory.geturl2(), 
                      myRequestsFactory.geturl3() ]);
      };

    return helperService;
});
```

Then in my controller ..

```
  function loadData() {
        helperService.GetAll().then(
          function(result) {
            $scope.url1result = result[0];
            $scope.url2result = result[1];
            $scope.url3result = result[2];

          });
      },
      function(error) {

      }
    );
  }
```

That's how i would get access to this data